# How to export an org file containing code blocks to a code file including comments?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Suppose I have the following org file (pdguide.org):

```
* Creating a Pandas =DataFrame=
  The pandas =DataFrame= can be created by loading the data from the external, existing storage like a database, SQL or CSV files. But the pandas =DataFrame= can also be created from the lists, dictionary, etc. One of the ways to create a pandas data frame is shown below:
  - import pandas library
    #+begin_src python
    import pandas as pd
    #+end_src
  - Dictionary of key pair values called data
    #+begin_src python
    data = {'Name':['NickD', 'John', 'Sam', 'crocefisso', 'Debbie'],
         'Age': [24, 23, 22, 19, 10]}
    #+end_src
  - Calling the pandas DataFrame method by passing the dictionary (data) as a parameter
    #+begin_src python
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df
    #+end_src
```

How can I export it to a pdguide.py so the parts that are not code blocks become comments?

Also would it be possible to have it exported as pdguide.ipynb so the part that are not code blocks become markdown?

Comment: Please don't use images. Org mode is plain text, so you can cut and paste it into a [markdown code block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: I already erased the org I wrote for the screenshot. I have tried to edit it as code, but it didn't work since it was transformed in md.

Comment: See the link and my answer for how to do it: all you have to do is surround it with two lines, each containing three backticks, one before the code and one after.

Comment: I added a small section of the text from your image as a markdown code block to illustrate the method. Hope it helps. Fee free to delete it (although I hope you will instead expand it to contain all the text in your image and get rid of the image instead ;-) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is called [tangling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html#Extracting-Source-Code).

All you have to do is provide a header arg to specify that, e.g.:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:python :tangle pdguide.py
```

After you add the line to your buffer, don't forget to refresh it by typing `C-c C-c` on the property line.

Then you can tangle the code into the file with `C-c C-v C-t`.

EDIT: you can include the nearest headline as comments (from the headline to the text before the code block) by using `:comments both` as a header arg: that will include the headline as a comment and will provide links back to the Org mode file for each code block. You can use `:comments org` for just the headline, or `:comment link` for just the links.

As for your last question: "Also would it be possible to have it exported as pdguide.ipynb so the part that are not code blocks become markdown?", AFAIK the answer is no. EDIT: The OP points out in a comment that something like this might be possible using [John Kitchin's 'ipynb' exporter](https://github.com/jkitchin/ox-ipynb).

Comment: When I tangle code, a .py is generated but without any comments.

Comment: As I said I wanted all the none code blocks to be exported as comments. In Python comments begin with a hash mark ( # ).

Comment: Edited the answer with some info: a small step towards what you want but certainly not the whole thing.

Comment: Thx,  `:comments org` works than `:comments both` though. As for ipynb export, I found this module https://github.com/jkitchin/ox-ipynb but didn't test it yet.

Comment: So here is the full line `#+PROPERTY: header-args :python :comments org :tangle filename.py`

Comment: No space between `header-args` and `:python` - see [Using Header Arguments](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html#Using-Header-Arguments)

Comment: I noticed that only sub headline close to the code block is exported, and none of the parent headlines are...